# Displaying a name of a non directly joined model in a pagination

Tags: cakephp

```
Press Story belongsTo Company
Company belongsTo Sector
```

Is there a way to display a list of the Press Stories, having the name of the company and the name of the sector?

The array returned by cake when paginating Press Stories contains Company and Press information but no additional information about the Sector.

Answer (score 0):

use `recursive => '2'` in find condition.

See [this link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive).

```
Ex: $this->Model->find('all', array('conditions' => array(....),
                                    'recursive' => '2'));
```

Comment: This link might help you to achieve the same: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#custom-query-pagination